# Cannot receive POST request from Instagram API

Tags: django, api, instagram, django-cors-headers

I am trying to create a real-time subscription to Instagram.

When Instagram sends to my callback uri a POST request, it is giving me a 403 error(forbidden error).

I think it is because external domains are not allowed to send post requests to my domain.

I tried to use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). I did:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

It does not seem to work. I still get the POST request with 403 status.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the reason. Much more likely is that you have not disabled csrf protection for that view, and Instagram obviously won't have your csrf cookie, so the request fails.

Make sure you decorate the relevant view with `django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt`.

Comment: I had this idea too but is it not a security issue?